# How to make div inside bootstrap column all have the same height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say I have this structure:

```
<div className="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div>TEST</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      <div>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I know how to make the columns of the same height (using the `.equal` class on the row) however, what I need is the child div of the column to also be of the same height. Currently, if one of the child divs is shorter, it won't look aligned because I set the background color to be in the child div and not on the `col-sm` div.

I cannot set the background on `col-sm` for flexibility reasons. E.g. I may need to use that child div component in another section that doesn't use `'col-sm'`.

Mine currently is the one on top, I want it to become the one at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Is this what you need? - https://jsfiddle.net/86v39qha/3/

Comment: @TiagoMartinho It does make it all the same height but it messes up the width. Originally col-sm uses flex-basis: 0 and flex-grow: 1

Comment: @David.J Think quite different issue..

Comment: and this - https://jsfiddle.net/86v39qha/16/

Answer (score 0):

A situation like this, for me, would be time to turn to jQuery or a plugin [such as MatchHeight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height).

> matchHeight makes the height of all selected elements exactly equal.